Problem with compiling .NET console app for linux
Good afternoon, everyone. I have written a simple discord bot and want to upload it to a VPS with Linux. In all the guides people normally open Publish Profiler and there you can choose linux-x64 platform. I have no such window (see below).
What i have
What another people have
I reinstalled MVS and it didn't help me. I also tried to build the project with the command "dotnet build MyAppName.csproj -- runtime linux-x64" but it again creates a build for Windows. Maybe I need to download something or create a different type of project? Result of compilation

Welcome to the SO. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. Or at least share contents of your .csproj file

The decision turned out to be a stupid one. I just once again demolished my visual studio and chose a different type of project to create.
